# How to Add Gmail Contact via iPhone

Tags: iphone, gmail, contacts

I have my [Gmail account configured via Exchange](http://support.google.com/mobile/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=138740) on my iPhone 4S.  When I add a new contact, it only adds it to my phone.  I have to add separately to Gmail and then merge duplicates, which seems like too many steps.

I want this to work so that any contact I add through iOS is added to my Gmail contacts, not the local phone's contacts.  How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the settings, set your default Contacts account to Gmail.

1. Launch **Settings**
2. Navigate to **Mail, Contacts, Calendars**
3. Scroll down to **Contacts**
4. Under default account, select the email address you use with Gmail.

Now whenever you create a contact on iOS, it will be added to Gmail. The only time a contact will not be added to Gmail is if you go into the **Contacts** application, select **Groups** on the top, and choose an account other than **All Contacts** or your Gmail account (e.g. iCloud).